# Dataframe for textfile Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm trying to create a data frame on a text file. For a sample input (**Input1**)
 below **Code** is working fine

**Input1**

```
1,5

2,6

3,7

4,8
```

**Output1**

```
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  1|   5|
|  2|   6|
|  3|   7|
|  4|   8|
+---+----+
```

However when I changed the input(**Input2**), I'm not getting any output.

**Input2**

```
1,"a,b,c"

2,"d,e,f"

3,"a,b,c"

4,"a,d,f"
```

**Output2**

```
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
+---+----+
```

**Code**

```
    {
        val input = sc.textFile(inputFile).map(x=>x.split(",")).collect {
                            case Array(id,name) => Record(id.toInt, name)
                    }
                    input.toDF().show()
    }
case class Record(id: Int, name: String)
```

**Expected output format for Input2**

```
+---+-----+------+-----+
| id|name1| name2|name3|
+---+-----+------+-----+
|  1|    a|     b|    c|
|  2|    d|     e|    d|    
|  3|    a|     b|    c|
|  4|    a|     d|    f|
+---+-----+------+-----+
```

I should make changes to the code and case class as well so that compiler understands the data format for **Input2**, but I'm not getting what changes I need to do.  Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Spark2, you can simply do

```
val df = spark.read.csv(inputFile)
```

And you can split apart the second column in following steps.

At the moment, you're trying to read an entire line containing more than one comma, and only matching on an Array of two elements

Comment: I'm using Spark 1.6. Is there any solution for Spark 1.6 version.

Comment: If you aren't able to simply download Spark 2, then https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @cricket_007

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make the *first digit* as `id` column and rest of the *comma separated chars* inside inverted comma as `name` column. For that you have to change a little bit of your logic and you should be fine as below

```
val input = sc.textFile(inputFile).map(x=>x.split(",")).map(x => Record(x.head.toInt, x.tail.mkString(",")))
input.toDF().show()
```

and of course `case class` is as you have

```
case class Record(id: Int, name: String)
```

You should have following `dataframe`

```
+---+-------+
| id|   name|
+---+-------+
|  1|"a,b,c"|
|  2|"d,e,f"|
|  3|"a,b,c"|
|  4|"a,d,f"|
+---+-------+
```

If you don't want the inverted comma you can add `replace` api as

```
val input = sc.textFile(inputFile).map(x=>x.replace("\"", "").split(",")).map(x => Record(x.head.toInt, x.tail.mkString(",")))
input.toDF().show()
```

you should have

```
+---+-----+
| id| name|
+---+-----+
|  1|a,b,c|
|  2|d,e,f|
|  3|a,b,c|
|  4|a,d,f|
+---+-----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful.

By the way its better to use sqlContext to read such files where you want to ignore the commas inside inverted commas.

```
sqlContext.read.format(inputFile).toDF("id", "name").show(false)
```

you should have above output dataframe

Comment: Thanks for the info @Ramesh Maharjan. I tried below solution and got the output as per my need.  val input11 = sc.textFile(inputFile).map(x=>x.replaceAll("\"",""))                                  val input22 = input11.map(x=>x.split(",")).collect {
     case Array(id,name,name1, name2) => Record(id.toInt, name, name1, name2)
   }

Comment: my pleasure @Ram. If the answer helped you can upvote :) And you can accept either mine or cricket_007 as both answers are helpful. the choice is yours. :)

Comment: did you change your Record case class? you are passing four arguments to your case class while Record case class expects only two.

Comment: I made the changes to record class. I need record class with the same number of arguments as the number of values.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the below code and got the output as per the need.

```
    {
        val input = sc.textFile(inputFile).map(x=>x.replaceAll("\"","")) 
        val input1 = input.map(x=>x.split(",")).collect { case Array(id,name,name1, name2) => Record(id.toInt, name, name1, name2) }
    }
    case class Record(id: Int, name: String, name1 : String, name2 : String)
```